# In reference to Vs with reference to

Tags: idioms

What is the difference between "in reference to" vs "with reference to".

For eg. If had a discussion with someone and I want to quote it in a mail, which one is more appropriate from the below 2 sentences?

"In reference to your discussion with Mr. X, ...."
VS
"With reference to your discussion with Mr. X, ...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They mean essentially the same thing, and which you use is a matter of personal preference.

The more common of the two [seems to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20reference%20to%2C%20with%20reference%20to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cin%20reference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20reference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20reference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwith%20reference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwith%20reference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWith%20reference%20to%3B%2Cc0) *with*.